# Change layout in the controller of Zend Framework 2.0

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am learning **ZF2.0 beta**. In ZF1 we can change layout on the fly in controller:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('layoutname');
```

But in **ZF2.0** Zend\Layout class doesn't has method getMvcInstance(). I think that it can be made using dependency injections but not sure.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The ZF2 is heavily under development and no guarantee can be made the way it works now, will be the way it works when ZF2 reaches a stable state.

However, the new view layer from Zend\Mvc is recently merged so you should be able to do this now (with current master):

```
public function somethingAction () 
{
    // Do some intelligent work

    $this->layout('layout/different');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this approach, but I don't get the result. Layout is still standart (`layout/layout`). Why it doesn't work? You can read more about my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690184/how-to-change-layout-in-controller-in-zendframework2).

Answer (score 8):

```
public function someAction() {
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTemplate('layout/custom');
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for multiple layouts when changing existing Layouts

Comment: It looks like working, but id doesn't work for me :( [image](http://i.gyazo.com/2082ae68e20ade4edee81858f6ae9b8f.png) which shows my code. I don't know why it doesn't work :'(

Answer (score 7):

The best way I've found to set templates in actions is like this

```
public function someAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/custom');

    return $viewModel;
}
```

In your `module.config.php` make sure you've set your appropriate `template_map` path.

```
    'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/custom' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/custom.phtml'
    ),
),
```

Comment: This will set view, but not layout, as author asked.

Answer (score 3):

You will also have to set the layout either in the bootstrap or when using di. Di example:

```
    'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver' => array(
        'parameters' => array(
            'map'  => array(
            'layout/different' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/different.phtml',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the above tips.

```
public function somethingAction () 
{
    // Do some intelligent work

    $this->layout('layout/different');
}
```

I got the correct result with this snippet.

```
public function someAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/custom');

    return $viewModel;
}
```

It fetched both layouts(default & current module).

Comment: I encountered the same result. I think it's important that we differentiate between layout and template. For changing the layout, we should be using $this->layout('layout/different'); instead of the setTemplate function.

Comment: Code in your snippet will set what view will be rendered, not layout.