# Custom layout from public folder in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have templates folder in my public folder.

I want to have opportunity to upload different layouts form my admin panel and put them to public/templates folder.

How can I change standard layout then?

```
$template = 'christmas.phtml';
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('/../../public/templates/'.$template);
```

isn't working :(

I also tried this way (changing layout) up from current:

```
$this->layout('../../public/templates/'.$template);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I've added one line to my module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    ...
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
        __DIR__ . '/../../../public' // newLine
    ),
),
```

Then simply use this in controller:

```
$template = 'sometemplate.phtml';
$this->layout('templates/'.$template);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try `$viewModel->setTemplate(APPLICATION_PATH .'/../public/templates/'.$template);` or `$viewModel->setTemplate('./../../public/templates/'.$template);` instead of `$viewModel->setTemplate('/../../public/templates/'.$template);`. Because I guess you want to go up from the application directory, not from the root directory and `$template = 'christmas.phtml';` should be `$template = 'christmas';`

If there is no `APPLICATION_PATH` constant you can define it in index.php file. If you dont like to define it, you can use `realpath('<path/to/your/public/templates/>')` method.

Comment: The same result :( Server doesn't give any explanation, except of 500 error

Comment: where is your public folder located? in the application path or in your disk directory?

Comment: The structure is standard:
..
public -> 
 templates ->
  default.phtml,
module ->
 Application -> 
  src -> 
   Controller ->
    IndexController.php

Comment: ZF2 has no APPLICATION_PATH constant. :(

Comment: I think you should look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112766/change-layout-in-the-controller-of-zend-framework-2-0) for your help.

Comment: did you tried with `$template = 'christmas';` instead of `$template = 'christmas.phtml';`

Comment: Thank you for help, I've found the solution