# Defining multiple layouts in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 application which runs on several hosts for example:

```
www.site1.com
www.site2.com
www.site3.com
www.site4.com
www.site5.com
www.site6.com
```

All of these websites use only the same `layout.phtml` file which is called `layout.phtml`, and depending on the type of the website a different CSS skin is loaded for the layout file.

My question here is, how can I create a separate layout file for site6 so that it uses only that layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `ServerUrl` view helper](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.View.Helper.ServerUrl.html) for this. Check also [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22079626/1697459).

```
$serverUrl = $this->serverUrl(); // output: http://www.siteX.com
```

Then you can set a css or other specific layout things depending on the value of this variable. You could for example use [a php switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for that inside your view (in the `layout.html` file):

**In view:**

```
switch( $serverUrl ){
    case 'http://www.site1.com':
        // logic for site 1
        break;
    case 'http://www.site2.com':
        // logic for site 2
        break;
    case 'http://www.site3.com':
        // logic for site 3
        break;
    case 'http://www.site4.com':
        // logic for site 4
        break;
    case 'http://www.site5.com':
        // logic for site 5
        break;
    case 'http://www.site6.com':
        // logic for site 6
        break;
}
```

---

Alternatively you could also set a different layout in your controller depending on the value of `$serverUrl`. How to set a layout is also explained [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413957/1697459). So something like:

**In controller:**

```
$serverUrlHelper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl');
$serverUrl = $serverUrlHelper();

switch( $serverUrl ){
    case 'http://www.site1.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout1');
        break;
    case 'http://www.site2.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout2');
        break;
    case 'http://www.site3.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout3');
        break;
    case 'http://www.site4.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout4');
        break;
    case 'http://www.site5.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout5');
        break;
    case 'http://www.site6.com':
        $this->layout('layout/layout6');
        break;
}
```

Now I use a switch statement but there are probably like a 100 different ways to do this but that I leave up to your creativity.